# How do I remove ia32-libs from the Depends line as generated by shlibs:Depends?

Tags: packaging, dependencies

I've created a package which contains 32-bit libraries for compatibility with 32-bit applications on 64-bit systems, stored in `/usr/lib32`. This causes the `ia32-libs` dependency being added to my package. However, the package works perfectly fine without those libraries as other 32-bit programs should install `ia32-libs` themselves.

How do I prevent the build process from generating the `ia32-libs` dependency? `nvidia-current` seems to able to do this too, but uses CDBS which I do not use. (I use a plain `rules` file as generated by `dh_make`)

Comment: This doesn't make sense "as other 32-bit programs should install ia32-libs themselves."  So why do you care about the dependency?

Comment: The package in question is `virtualgl`. This program provides 32-bit libraries in order to work with 32-bit programs. Without those 32-bit programs, the 32-bit libs are obsolete so I do not want the package to depend on the huge `ia32-libs`.

Comment: So a multiarch package?

Comment: @Steve-o: Not a multi-arch package for now, I'm targetting Lucid and Maverick too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make debhelper ignore the 32-bit libraries, I had to add a target for ignoring paths **containing** `/usr/lib32`:

```
override_dh_shlibdeps:
    dh_shlibdeps --exclude=/usr/lib32
```

After that, the ia32-libs dependencies would not be calculated anymore. Since this target is only needed for 64-bit systems, I actually use the below snippet for the virtualgl package:

```
ifeq ($(DEB_BUILD_ARCH), amd64)
override_dh_shlibdeps:
    dh_shlibdeps --exclude=debian/virtualgl/usr/lib32
endif
```

Note that the whitespace before `dh` is a **tab**.

Answer (score 0):

Removal of the `ia32-libs` dependency is explicitly covered in the Debian Multiarch Implementation guide:

http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/Implementation

Which basically means if there are certain dpkg tools that are emitting too many packages when specifying multiarch then it is a tool bug and now is a good time to file a report.